# How to prevent visual studio from overwriting the IISExpress applicationhost.config file settings in MVC5 project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, iis-express, asp.net-mvc-5

In my solution path there is a config file located at:

> solutiondirectory\.vs\config\applicationhost.config

In that config file there is a security node which is overwritten at various times and is messing up my application during development.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

The problem is that windowsAuthentication is being overwritten and set to true at random times and I have to manually reset it to false.

My MVC5 project has the following security setup in the web.config file

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="300" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

My project has the following property settings

[image: project properties]

I have read some other posts about this and that is how I found out about the file and the property settings, but my solution is still overwriting my windows authentication setting.  Does anyone know why or how to prevent it?

Comment: Mark the file as read only?

Comment: @will i'm not sure if that will work, but it avoids the core problem.  I'm thinking there is another project/solution setting I don't know about, or perhaps I have implemented my forms authentication wrong?  I'd like to get to the root problem.